# How to compare 2 lists with each other in Python?

Tags: python, list, lambda, python-itertools

I have the following 2 lists.

```
my_values = ['0,78', '0,40', '0,67']

my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '190,00', '0,15'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,90', '0,32'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,38', '0,44'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,94', '0,60'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,49', '0,78'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '187,99', '0,101'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,76', '0,10'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,16', '0,20'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,56', '0,35'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,01', '0,40'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '188,13', '0,75'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '187,95', '0,85'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,20', '0,11'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,10', '0,31'], 
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '189,32', '0,45'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,61', '0,67'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,01', '0,72'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '187,36', '0,80']]
```

Now for every lists in `my_list` I want to check at what `index[2]` is `index[3]` equal to a value in `my_values.`  `index[2]` is the 3th row in `my_list` and `index[4]` is the 4th row in `my_list` So short said:

1. For Morocco I want to check at what `index[2]` is `index[3]` == `0,78`
2. For Spain I want to check at what `index[2]` is `index[3]` == `0,40`
3. For Italy I want to check at what `index[2]` is `index[3]` == `0,67`

This is the code I tried:

```
my_answers = []
for key,sublists in itertools.groupby(my_list,lambda y:y[0]): 
    v = min(x for x in sublists if float(x[3].replace(',', '.')) == x for x in my_values); 
    my_answers.append(v[-2])
    
print(my_answers)
```

This is what I receive:

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

This is what I expected:

```
188,49
189,01
188,61
```

Comment: what is `index[2]` and `index[3]`?
oh, you mean 3rd and 4th element of each sublist

Comment: @Capie `index[2]` is the 3th row in `my_list` and index[4] is the 4th row in `my_list`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
my_values = ['0,78', '0,40', '0,67']

my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '190,00', '0,15'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,90', '0,32'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,38', '0,44'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,94', '0,60'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,49', '0,78'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '187,99', '0,101'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,76', '0,10'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,16', '0,20'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,56', '0,35'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,01', '0,40'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '188,13', '0,75'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '187,95', '0,85'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,20', '0,11'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,10', '0,31'], 
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '189,32', '0,45'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,61', '0,67'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,01', '0,72'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '187,36', '0,80'],
]

print("\n".join(i[2] for i in my_list if i[3] in my_values))
```

Output:

```
188,49
189,01
188,61
```

Here's what the one-liner does:

- loops over the lists in your `my_list` and checks the value from each sub-list with the index `[3]` againts the `my_value` list
- if the condition is `True`, it "keeps" the value from index `[2]`
- finally it joins all the `values` that matched the above e.g. `189,01`
- By the way, the `i[2] for i in my_list if i[3] in my_values` is a generator
- `"\n"` is a new line character

EDIT:

If you want the output to be in a list, just do this:

```
yet_another_list = [i[2] for i in my_list if i[3] in my_values]
print(yet_another_list)
```

This gives you:

```
['188,49', '189,01', '188,61']
```

Comment: thats a very strong one-liner. I think it does the job. Can you just detailed tell me what you exactly did so I know where to think about if my data ever changes?

Comment: What does the `'\n'` do in your code? By the way... I would like the output to be in a list

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in my_list:
     if i[3] in my_values:
         print(i[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to dataframe and use np.where

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(my_list)
df['Filter']=np.where([i in my_values for i in df[3]],"Yes","")
my_out_list=list(df[2][df['Filter']=='Yes'])
```

output:

```
my_out_list
Out[18]: ['188,49', '189,01', '188,61']
```

Comment: What if I want to place it in a list?

Comment: @TangerCity Just replace print with list.  I've edited the answer to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend migrating that list to a list of dictionary instead, it should make accessing values easier for you:

Change your list to something like:

```
my_list = [
 {'country': 'Morocco', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '190,00', 'num2': '0,15'},
 {'country': 'Morocco', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '189,90', 'num2': '0,32'},
 {'country': 'Morocco', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '189,38', 'num2': '0,44'},
 {'country': 'Morocco', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '188,94', 'num2': '0,60'},
 {'country': 'Morocco', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '188,49', 'num2': '0,78'},
 {'country': 'Morocco', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '187,99', 'num2': '0,101'},
 {'country': 'Spain', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '190,76', 'num2': '0,10'},
 {'country': 'Spain', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '190,16', 'num2': '0,20'},
 {'country': 'Spain', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '189,56', 'num2': '0,35'},
 {'country': 'Spain', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '189,01', 'num2': '0,40'},
 {'country': 'Spain', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '188,13', 'num2': '0,75'},
 {'country': 'Spain', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '187,95', 'num2': '0,85'},
 {'country': 'Italy', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '190,20', 'num2': '0,11'},
 {'country': 'Italy', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '190,10', 'num2': '0,31'},
 {'country': 'Italy', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '189,32', 'num2': '0,45'},
 {'country': 'Italy', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '188,61', 'num2': '0,67'},
 {'country': 'Italy', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '188,01', 'num2': '0,72'},
 {'country': 'Italy', 'category': 'Meat', 'num1': '187,36', 'num2': '0,80'}
]
```

And then you can simply:

```
for record in my_list:
    if record['num2'] in my_values:
        print(f"{record['num2']} {record['num1']}")
```

or as a one-liner:

```
print("\n".join(f"{record['num2']} {record['num1']}" for record in my_values if record['num2'] in my_values))
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it in this manner -

```
my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '190,00', '0,15'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,90', '0,32'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,38', '0,44'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,94', '0,60'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,49', '0,78'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '187,99', '0,101'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,76', '0,10'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,16', '0,20'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,56', '0,35'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,01', '0,40'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '188,13', '0,75'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '187,95', '0,85'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,20', '0,11'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,10', '0,31'], 
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '189,32', '0,45'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,61', '0,67'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,01', '0,72'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '187,36', '0,80']]
my_answers = []
for U_list in my_list:
    if U_list[0] == "Morocco" and U_list[3] == "0,78":
        my_answers.append(U_list[2])
    if U_list[0] == "Spain" and U_list[3] == "0,40":
        my_answers.append(U_list[2])
    if U_list[0] == "Italy" and U_list[3] == "0,67":
        my_answers.append(U_list[2])
print(my_answers)
```